# how to create a custom hover event with a pin?

Tags: apex, visualforce

[image]

I want to show   my vf page on hover event of record on another vf page just like mini page layout but  standard mini page layout will not help me because i  need a Pin option. This means allow the hover to be pinned to the page so it can be reviewed.

Answer (score -1):

Here is something i found for you.This is example for hover on command link,you can implement it on Custom Button with pin Image. And You Have to use visualforce page to override standard functionality.

You can add the same JS to the link that Salesforce adds. Here is an example.

```
<apex:outputLink id="complink" 
       onblur="LookupHoverDetail.getHover(this.id).hide();" 
       onmouseout="LookupHoverDetail.getHover(this.id).hide();" 
       onfocus="LookupHoverDetail.getHover(this.id, '/{!row['Contact']['AccountId']}/m?retURL=%2Fapex%2FCampaignCallList%3FscontrolCaching%3D1%26id%3D{!Camp.Id}&isAjaxRequest=1&nocache=1418312066674').show();" 
       onmouseover="LookupHoverDetail.getHover(this.id, '/{!row['Contact']['AccountId']}/m?retURL=%2Fapex%2FCampaignCallList%3FscontrolCaching%3D1%26id%3D{!Camp.Id}&isAjaxRequest=1&nocache=1418312066674').show();"
       value="/{!row['Contact']['AccountId']}">
    <apex:outputText value="{!row['Contact']['Account']['CUSTOM__Company_Name__c']}">
</apex:outputLink>
```

You do need to give the link an ID
inside the onmouseover and onfocus event handlers is a reference to the page you're calling from. In this case `/CampaignCallList?Id={!a campaign id}` but you should replace with your own details.

It's the URL that gets passed to `LookupHoverDetail.getHover` that determines the content of the hover. Make sure it's the ID of the record you want to view like `/001000000000001?.....`

Salesforce advise against using their JS like this as it isn't a published API and can be changed without notice, causing your code to stop working.

Comment: im sorry i m new to the salesforce, i tried to get this piece of code work but i could not. Can you give me some working code. Thanks